# Prerequisites for the book "Three-dimensional geometry and topology"

Tags: geometry, reference-request, manifolds, book-recommendation, geometric-topology

I am a mathematics student who want to read the book **Three-dimensional geometry and topology** written by **William P. Thurston**. But I am wondering whether I had enough background for this book or not. About my background, beside the undergraduate mathematics courses, I have taken several advanced courses: Abstract Algebra, Topology, Analysis on Manifold. I also read the following books:

- Abstract Algebra by David S. Dummit and Richard M. Foote.
- Topology by James Munkres.
- Analysis on Manifolds by James Munkres.
- Introduction to Smooth Manifolds by John M.Lee.

Do I need something else in order to read and understand this book ? If yes, can you please recommend me some other textbooks (and the order to read it) before start reading this book ?

Comment: You cannot read mathematics the way you read a novel. If you zip through a page
in less than an hour, you are probably going too fast. When you encounter the phrase
as you should verify, you should indeed do the verification, which will usually require
some writing on your part. When steps are left out, you need to supply the missing
pieces. You should ponder and internalize each definition. For each theorem, you
should seek examples to show why each hypothesis is necessary.-Halmos

Comment: I think you should try this [book](https://www.amazon.com/Three-Dimensional-Geometry-Topology-Vol-1/dp/0691083045)

Comment: Hi @jasmine, I know that those books I mentioned in my post, I read them very carefully, I even did manual solutions of the exercises on my own.  It took me a long time to finish this. That why I am asking people this question to ensure that when I start reading this book, I am able to fully understand it. Do you think I have enough background ?

Comment: that are long enough and have sufficient

Comment: @jasmine Have you read this book before? What do you think about this book? Is it good for learning low dimensional geometry ?

Comment: It is nice but, in many ways, informal and I would not recommend learning 3d topology from it.

Comment: @MoisheKohan In your opinion, Which book is good to start ? Can you recommend me some ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is not to use Thurston's book as the first introductory textbook for the subject.

Try

*Schultens, Jennifer*, Introduction to 3-manifolds, Graduate Studies in Mathematics 151. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 978-1-4704-1020-9/hbk). x, 286 p. (2014). [ZBL1295.57001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1295.57001).

It is sufficiently gentle and you have the right prerequisites. You can also supplement it with freely available:

A. Hatcher. Notes on Basic 3-Manifold Topology.  [https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/3M/3Mdownloads.html](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/3M/3Mdownloads.html)

For more in-depth treatment, I would suggest

*Hempel, John*, 3-manifolds, Annals of Mathematics Studies, 86. Princeton, New Jersey: Princeton University Press and University of Tokyo Press. XII, 195 p. hbk: $ 17.00; pbk: $ 6.25 (1976). [ZBL0345.57001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0345.57001).."

If you decide to read Thurston's book, I suggest you first read an introductory Riemannian Geometry textbook; my personal preference is do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry" (at least the first four chapters). Namely, you need to know definitions of Riemannian metrics, connections and curvature.

But there are many nice alternatives, such as Jack Lee's "Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds" book.

Also take a look [here](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/Other/topologybooks.pdf) for Hatcher's list of suggestions for geometric topology books.

Comment: In the second to last paragraph, do you mean *John* Lee's "Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds"?

Comment: @ElliotYu: Yes, it is the same person, https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/.

Comment: I see. I did not know he goes by Jack. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @ElliotYu: Similarly, for a long time, I did not know that he is also John!